# Can I increase my SPECIAL stats later in the game?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm setting my SPECIAL stats and I don't know how irreparable this damage will be... How will I be able to modify my SPECIAL stats after leaving the vault, if at all?

Theoretically, could I get each stat to 10 over the course of the game?

Answer (score 2):

Your SPECIAL stats can be permanently raised by finding certain [bobbleheads](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault-Tec_bobblehead#Fallout_4) throughout the world.

There are two ways to permanently increase your SPECIAL stats in Fallout 4:

1. Finding certain [bobbleheads](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault-Tec_bobblehead#Fallout_4) throughout the world
2. Spending a perk point to raise a stat, in lieu of gaining a perk

You can *temporarily* raise your SPECIAL stats through chems, armor, and food.

Comment: The book in the baby's room will also raise one score a point.  And since there's no level cap, you can get all stats to 10 (or 11!) and still get all the perks you want, given time.